# Why doesn't Simple Injector have an IContainer abstraction like Unity?

Tags: dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, unity-container, simple-injector

I have used Unity for my last project and was generally pleased. But benchmarks have me thinking I may go with Simple Injector for my next project.

However, Simple Injector does not seem to have an interface for its `Container` class. This means that anytime I want to use the container in a method, I cannot mock the container for unit testing.

I am confused how a tool that really functions based of interfaces, would not itself make an interface to the container. I know that the classic methods of dependency injection do not need the container for anywhere more than the startup. (The rest uses constructor injection.) But I have found that when the rubber hits the road that cannot always be true. Sometimes you just need the container in order to do a "resolve" in the code.

If I go with Simple Injector then that code seems to gets harder to unit test.

Am I right? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Why don't use an abstract factory instead of inject the container?

Answer (score 12):

Simple Injector does not contain an `IContainer` abstraction, because:

- It would be useless for Simple Injector to define it,
  because in case of depending on `IContainer` instead of `Container`, your code would in that case still depend on Simple Injector, and this causes a vendor lock-in, which Simple Injector [tries to prevent](https://simpleinjector.org/principles#don-t-force-vendor-lock-in).
- Any code you write, apart from the application's [Composition Root](https://mng.bz/K1qZ), should not depend on the container, nor on an abstraction over the container. Both are implementations of the [Service Locator anti-pattern](https://mng.bz/WaQw).
- You should NOT use a DI library when unit testing. When unit testing, you should manually inject all fake or mock objects in the class under test. Using a container only complicates things. Perhaps you are using a container, because manually creating those classes is too cumbersome for you. This might indicate problems with your code (you might be violating the [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle)) or your tests (you might be missing a [factory method to create the class under test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26484696/simple-injector-cant-override-existing-registration/26485923#26485923)).
- You might use the container for your integration tests, but you
  shouldn't have that many integration tests in the first place. The focus should be on unit tests and this should be easy when applying the dependency injection pattern. On top of that, there are better ways of hiding the container from your integration tests, compared to depending on a very wide library-defined interface.
- It is trivial to define such interface (plus an adapter) yourself, which justifies not having it in the library. It is your job as application developer to define the right abstractions for your application as stated by the [Dependency Inversion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle). Libraries and frameworks that tend to do this will fail most of the time in providing an abstraction that works for everyone.
- The library itself does not use that abstraction and a library should, according to the [Framework Design Guidelines](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321545613), in that case not define such abstraction for you. As stated in the previous point, Simple Injector would get the abstraction wrong anyway.
- Last but not least, the Simple Injector container does actually implement [System.IServiceProvider](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iserviceprovider.aspx) which is defined in mscorlib.dll and can be used for retrieving service objects.

Comment: I am not wanting to use the container in my tests.  I am wanting to unit test a method that uses the container.  In that case, I cannot mock the container to not use the full SimpleInjector logic.

Comment: OK, we are going to try this different than how we do Unity.  For Unity we mock the IContainer to return mocks.  That way Unity is not used (tested) by our unit tests.  We are going to try SimpleInjector.  We will pass a test version the container to the constructor of the object under test (when needed).  That test version will be setup to return mocks.  So in essence we will use the SimpleInjector stuff in our tests to return mocks, but in production it will return the objects that are setup at start up.  I feel I have to give it a try because SimpleInjector is just so darn fast!!!

Comment: But why earth does that class have a dependency on the container? Classes that have (enough) logic to test should not depend on he container directly. Only infrastructure components (that are part of your composition root) should have a dependency on the container or an abstraction of the container. You are clearly having trouble testing your system, because you violate this rule.

Comment: Most of the time we don't need the container.  (Though sometimes we find it useful limit the number of params in the constructor.)  But we have run into times where we need the container to resolve us an object inline.  And it can't be done via a constructor injection.  That is where having an IContainer is very useful.

Comment: If you inject the container to "limit the number of parameters" this probably means that this class does too much; violates the Single Respinsibility Principle. Please reconsider your strategy. I'm passionate about fighting this kind of abuse of the container. If you're in doubt, please post some real life examples of a class that gets a container injected herr on SO, or mail me directly. I'll be happy to explain how you can change the design in such way that the problem dissappears.

Comment: The parameters are all due to Single Responsibility issues.  I have an IPatientService, IDoctorService, IConfigService, IRegionAdapter, IRequistionHelpService, ISearchService and several more.  If I have a piece of UI that needs them all, then I end up with a lot of constructor parameters.  Frankly I don't mind.  But some of my team members complain about it.

Comment: That UI is clearly violating SRP and this will lead to maintainability issues, but so are classes that ens with the name *Service, *Manager, *Helper, etc. We call them [God Classes](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?GodClass). Your application might benefit from a different design. Take a look at [this article](http://bit.ly/s7tGEH) and [this article](http://bit.ly/s3UUyv) to get some ideas about how to improve the design of your application.

Comment: Maybe in a perfect world you can have UI that is Single Responsibility.  Unfortunately, my UI has to perform as my Product Owner requires.  And frequently they want a UI that will assist them in doing several things.

Comment: That still doesn't force you do to use a single UI component. You can ofren still build up that UI using multiple user controls, partials, or what ever the name is in the UI technology you use. You can compose that screen out of multiple parts.

Comment: That is what we do.  But the UI that holds it all components still needs all the references.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer given here is entirely founded upon accepting that ServiceLocator is an anti-pattern, which in turn I don't believe is globally accepted as true. See Windows Workflow Foundation's Extensions support.

The anti-pattern link (and its two updates) may also be weak... the latest update claims violation of encapsulation ("relieving you of the burden of having to understand every implementation detail of every piece of code in your code base.") while then at the same time claiming that up-front knowledge of dependencies is somehow different for that claim than discovering them via unit tests. Either way, you're going to need to know what to give it.

All in all, if you want to follow the Locator pattern, either leverage its IServiceProvider, or simplify your container population (to a singleton) and create a static wrapper for it.