# Is it considered poor DI practice to include your app container within the constructor of a service?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, simple-injector

First, I'm using Simple Injector but I think this question could apply to any DI framework.

When creating services to be registered for an application, is it considered bad practice to pass the services container into the service through its constructor?

For instance.  Consider the following code.

```
//IServiceInterface.cs
interface IServiceInterface {}

//MyService.cs
//All standard using statements here...
using SimpleInjector;

class MyService : IServiceInterface
{
    private _container {get; set;}

    public MyService(Container container) 
    {
        _container = container;

        //Construct!
    }
}

//MyApp.cs

public Contrainer container;
....

//My application bootstrapper method
void Bootstrap()
{
    var container = new Container();
    container.RegisterSingle<IServiceInterface >(() => new MyService(container));
    container.Verify();
    this.container = container;
}
```

As you can see from the method above, I define a service class that takes a Simple Injector container.  When I register the container, I pass the container that is associated with my app, to the service.

This seems like a useful approach when you are defining a service that will be in a separate project, that may even be in a different namespace, that will need to register new services at some point in the application's lifecycle.  However, I've not seen this done in any example and before I try anything like this, I want to makes sure that this approach is correct.

Is this behavior considered good DI practice?  If not, how do you obtain your applications DI container, and register new services as they are needed from within a service?

**UPDATE -- ADDITIONAL DETAILS**

I decided to start using Dependency Injection for a new project that I have for two reasons.  One, this is a massive project that will probably include 10-12 Visual Studio projects and, second,  many of these projects contain code that I've copied and pasted from one application, to another over the years and then slightly modified as they have been needed.  Enough of this, it's time to write my own business-logic framework that works with our company, as we need it to.

This first, big project seemed like the place to start with DI and my homebrew framework.  To build and test this application one-layer at a time, I'm defining a lot of interfaces and "shell" service classes.  This way, I can just wire up my top-level application, and update the dependencies as their projects are completed and linked into my solution.

Since this is such a LARGE application, I have services, that will need to depend on services... that will depend further on services.

My thought was that my application should only register the services that it will need to authenticate my users and load views.  The View services should register the Model views.  The ModelView services should register their associated Model services, which will register database connectivity services... sigh, which will EVENTUALLY register a server-side, synchronization service, that will register a local DB connection service AND web application service.  Phew!  Sound confusing?  Well, it kind of is.

My thought was that I could define these classes that can take a Container object, and then each service would use the container to either obtain any underlying service that may already exist, or instantiate a new one if one hasn't been created.

For instane, my user Auth service may cache information through an `ILocalDB` service that should be shared with my Model services.  If I register all of these services when I boot up my app, the app will be sluggish an the whole registration will look pretty gnarly.

I assume there has to be an elegant solution to this.  What am I missing?

Comment: Your last sentence sounds completely backwards to me. The container should register services, and services themselves use of the container to retrieve services.  Not vice versa.

Comment: I might be coming at this from an incorrect perspective.  But, consider it from the idea that you have a "controlling" application that depends on services like authentication, multiple DB updates, server communication stacks, etc. etc.  Within each of these (rather large) services, numerous services exist that may need to be registered and shared amongst one another.  The top-level application may not care whether an authorization service, depends on  a db sync service, that depends on a web service-- it just wants to load the authorization service so a user can log in. (continued...)

Comment: How do you design your services so that they can depend on an applications service register, yet also not be aware of the application of itself.  My services do not need to be aware of their owner, but they may want to share the services it's using and has registered.  I could be confused.  Probably am, but I want to get this right.  Also, I'll admit.  I see Factory code every where, I see what it's doing, but I thinking I'm missing the point of factory methods.  That could be part of my problem.

Comment: While the services know nothing about the application, they should also know nothing about the DI container.  The DI container lives in the top-level project, that is the application, and is responsible for instantiating all service objects, and feeding them any dependencies.  So, if an auth service depends on a DB service, it should express that by asking for IDBService in its constructor.  (Sorry, maybe I'm not understanding -- a more concrete example might help.)

Comment: No, I think you understand.  I guess, my method of passing the container around seemed to make more since than having 4-5 levels of constructors. (i.e., services, being injected into services, being into services, being injected into services...) especially if I may need to lazy-load some of these services when they are needed.

Comment: But complexity of constructor injection, and the need for lazy loading, are both fine -- those are the problems that the DI container is meant to solve.  1. As long as you've registered every dependency type with the container, then you should never have to manually call one of those complex constructors.  2. DI containers have tools to manage object scope:  http://simpleinjector.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=ObjectLifestyleManagement&referringTitle=Home

Comment: Thanks @McGarnagle.  I'll read that documentation article (Again.)  I read it (ok, skimmed it) earlier in my information gathering.  I probably need to slow down a bit.

Comment: Injecting the container is a variation of the Service Locator pattern. A lot has been written about it here on Stackoverflow. It is not a good pattern. Please read this article: http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern/

Comment: @Steven: I've read the article and I understand Mark Seemann's argument. Post an answer with a 1-2 sentence summary, and a decent explanation of how to resolve dependencies, deep within projects that depend on other dependencies and you have the answer mark.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to the basic question in the title has already been answered by @Steven - yes it is generally considered bad practice to inject the container into any classes. @Steven is the author of SimpleInjector and firmly sticks by this principle - [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16225737/simpleinjector-vs-unity-wheres-the-icontainer)

It’s unclear to me what else you are asking but here’s some info that may help.

- SimpleInjector does not normally recommend registering services throughout the applications lifetime and it is preferred that all registrations are done at start up in the composition root. [See here](https://simpleinjector.org/ReferenceLibrary/?topic=html/E_SimpleInjector_Container_ResolveUnregisteredType.htm)

> When the first type is resolved from the container, the container is locked for further changes. When a call to one of the registration methods is made after that, the container will throw an exception. The container can't be unlocked. This behavior is fixed and can't be changed. If it must be possible to register new types after this point, unregistered type resolution can be used.

- If you have objects that take some time to instantiate then you can inject `Lazy<>` instances so that an instance is not instantiated until/unless it is explicitly referenced in the calling path of your code. [See here](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.org/en/latest/howto.html#register-factory-delegates)
- Object Lifetime Management should deal with all the intricacies of passing in an existing instance / instantiating a new one. [See here](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.org/en/latest/lifetimes.html)
- To keep the registration process from becoming “gnarly” you could divide the process into classes that each registers an area of your solution e.g. DAL, CommandHandlers, Services, etc. These classes should be internal to the composition root that is responsible for bootstrapping the entire application and the whole bootstrap process is only called once at start-up. The composition root does not even need explicit references to all of the assemblies containing all of the implementations in your solution; it simply requires references to all of the services you have defined. [See here](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.org/en/latest/advanced.html#registering-plugins-dynamically) [and here](https://simpleinjector.codeplex.com/discussions/430774)

Comment: There are gaps in my understanding of some of this material, which is why you might not be fully understanding my question-- I may not be asking my questions correctly.  Still, I think you've provided enough useful information to point me in the right direction.  Thank you.

Comment: @RLH I completely understand - 9 months ago I'd not heard of DI.

Comment: Great answer. Nothing to add.

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion, passing in the container is not good design. You are essentially passing in a generic object construction factory, and so bypass the value inherent in being explicit about your dependencies. In practice you could just as well declare a static property for `container` on your Service class.

If I need to construct objects dynamically, I usually pass in a factory instead of an explicit instance. Like, passing in an ILogFactory instead of just an instance of ILog. This makes it apparent from the code what things are constructed dynamically, at the cost of a few factories and constructor parameters.

Another option, if you do not have a need to create multiple instances of the dependencies, but you know you will only need some of them, is to ensure that object construction is light-weight. Then it will not matter that you declare all dependencies explicitly, since they will only occur a cost if you actually use them.

Comment: I'm very new to all of this.  I see the "need" for DI, but this is such a massive topic.  I'll try to research a bit more from this perspective and get back with any questions or thoughts.  Thank you.