# MSTest/Simple Injector: access service reference in created instance in order to mock one of its methods

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mstest, simple-injector

I have a class depending on a service.  I have registered it thus:

```
container.Register<IMain, Main>();
container.Register<IChild, Child>();
```

When writing tests for this class, I want to mock one of the methods in IChild.  So I have mockIChild.Setup(...etc).

But you can't Register mock types so I'm gonna have to instantiate Main by hand in the tests, right?

Or is there something whizzy buried in the depths of Simple Injector or MSTest that could do the equivalent of:

```
[TestMethod]
public void foo()
{
    var mockChild = new Mock<IChild>();
    var main = container.GetInstance<IMain>(
       () => new Mock<IMain>(mockChild));
    mockChild.Setup(and so on...)'
}
```

?

Cheers,
.pd.

29-09-17 - thanks to everyone who provided answers.

Comment: The question in its current state is unclear as it is incomplete. Read [ask] and then provide a [mcve] that can be used to better understand your problem.

Comment: Not an exact duplicate, but the answer is spot on IMO https://stackoverflow.com/a/26485923/3294832

Comment: Well, @Ric.Net, my answer at least seems to be an exact duplicate of that answer :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When it comes to unit testing, refrain from using a DI Container to construct the class under test. Instead build up the class with its mocked dependencies manually.

A good pattern I discovered over the year is to use a private factory method inside the test class that allows constructing the class under test:

```
private static Main CreateMain(
    IChild child = null, ILogger logger = null, IMessageSender sender = null)
{
    return new Main(
        child: child ?? new Mock<IChild>().Object,
        logger: logger ?? new Mock<ILogger>().Object,
        messageSender: sender ?? new Mock<IMessageSender>().Object);
}
```

This factory method allows optionally supplying dependencies. Any missing dependency will be filled in automatically. This has the following advantages:

- It prevents every unit test from having to create the class under test itself. Which causes repeatitive code and noise.
- It prevents a change to the class under test constructor to cause every test in the test class to change. If a dependency is added, non of the existing tests change; only the factory method.
- A Unit test only has to define the dependencies it explicitly wants to assert on. This simplifies the test, because it removes noise of unneeded dependencies.
- It allows the test to define its own mock dependencies, instead of placing all mocks in private fields, instantiated by a `Setup` method. A `Setup` method causes the the test logic to be split to multiple places, and causes the test to be less readable, because it becomes hard to see which dependencies are being used.

This is how this factory method can be used:

```
public void Test()
{
    // Arrange
    var child = new Mock<IChild>();

    var main = CreateMain(child: child.Object);

    // Act
    main.DoSomething();

    // Assert
    Assert.IsTrue(child.ExpectSomethingOnChild);
}
```